# NodeJs save multiple files in MongoDb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, multer

I have a problem, I want to save multiple files at once in a database(MongoDb), but it does not work. It's save that id and nothing else

I put 2 files and in base its store like that 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaWci.jpg)

*My JS code*

```
var storage =   multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, callback) {
       callback(null, './uploads/');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, callback) {
       callback(null, file.originalname);
    }
});

var upload = multer({storage: storage, dest: './uploads/'}).array('userPhoto', 12);

app.post('/addfile',upload,function(req,res){
    var file = new File ();
        file.fieldname= req.files.fieldname;
        file.originalname= req.files.originalname;
        file.encoding= req.files.encodin;
        file.save(function(err, data){
           if (err){console.log(err)}
           else {
              console.log(req.files);
           }
    });
    res.end("File is uploaded");
});
```

*My HTML code*

```
<form id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/addfile" method="post">
   <input type="file" name="userPhoto" multiple=""/><br/>
   <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi Valentin Valentyn, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can I ask you to expand a bit on your question - can you describe precisely what you expect to happen, and compare that to what actually happens? Assuming you have been able to run this code through a debugger, then an analysis of the variable state would be useful too.

Comment: Hi, I use multer to retrieve the file data (file name, size etc.) and save its data in the mongo database.

And I want to save this data in the database at once.

Comment: Hi Valentin Valentyn; when you say "_It's save that id and nothing else_", that's not really enough detail for us to understand what is going wrong. Which _id_ is being saved - and to where? Maybe it would be useful if you [edit] your question to paste in an example of the data being saved, compared to what you were expecting to see in the database.